# Xcode 6.3.2 unexpectedly crashing on App Store submission

Tags: crash, xcode6.3

I was about to submit my app for TestFlight testers , the Xcode has crashed for 6th consecutive time and it is still crashing , I'm just hanged in the middle .
Any suggestions what to do ?
Thank you in advance for the help.

```
Process:               Xcode [1917]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.2 (7718)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7718000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812404257
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1917]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-06-19 01:33:40.608 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A178w)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        57E10C47-E9AB-1E21-571F-0266BDEB40A0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       5BCA9BD6-143D-4AD5-99F6-AA65136E904E

Time Awake Since Boot: 5500 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        12  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7f9c3d58d7d0 :: NSOperation 0x7f9c3ea294e0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)

 Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
 Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
 Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY


  0  0x0000000109ceab6a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x0000000108a445df _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000108a448ce _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001093b848e +[IDEIssueManager _issueProviderInfo] (in IDEFoundation)
  4  0x00000001093b7b0d -[IDEIssueManager _updateIssueProviders] (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x0000000108a573de __73-[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x00000001089ccd5c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x000000010887e3e4 -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff94734508 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff9474107d NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff946fa63f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff915ba4ff doSetValuesInSourceWithKVO (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x00007fff915ba366 _CFXPreferencesReplaceValuesInNamedVolatileSource ( (in CoreFoundation)
 13  0x00007fff948e0a51 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in Foundation)
 14  0x000000011ef6ea13 -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) REPLACEMENT_setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 15  0x000000011ef6ef87 -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) synchronizeRegistrationDomains] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 16  0x000000011ef6ed5d -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) registerPriorityDefaults:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 17  0x000000011ef6069e -[MZJSONServiceClient processApplicationSettings:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 18  0x000000011ef60d7d -[MZJSONServiceClient connectionDidFinishLoading:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 19  0x00007fff8a26293e __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)
 20  0x00007fff8a2627b2 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] (in CFNetwork)
 21  0x00007fff8a2626b7 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] (in CFNetwork)
 22  0x00007fff8a263734 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)
 23  0x00007fff8a33d7cd ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 (in CFNetwork)
 24  0x00007fff85c54383 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  25  0x00007fff85c6a672 _dispatch_block_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 26  0x00007fff8a1be8c4 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) (in CFNetwork)
 27  0x00007fff915cb594 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 28  0x00007fff8a1be7bd RunloopBlockContext::perform() (in CFNetwork)
 29  0x00007fff8a1be598 MultiplexerSource::perform() (in CFNetwork)
 30  0x00007fff8a1be3ba MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) (in CFNetwork)

 VM Region Summary:
 ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=470.7M resident=0K(0%)    swapped_out_or_unallocated=470.7M(100%)
 Writable regions: Total=1.2G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.2G(100%)


  Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0A, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.2f44
  Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
  Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
  Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD,      0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
  AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5),      Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.48.2.10)
  Bluetooth: Version 4.4.0d69 15953, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
  Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
  Serial ATA Device: WDC WD10JPVX-22JC3T0, 1 TB
  Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
  USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
  USB Device: Hub
  USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
  USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
  USB Device: Hub
  USB Device: Hub
  USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
  USB Device: IR Receiver
  USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
    USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
  Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Had the same issue right now, use application loader

In your xcode window --> organizer, click export and Save for iOS app store deployment.

save the ipa file somewhere you can access
open application loader and upload to app store